# Add intermediate certificates to Adobe Acrobat Reader truststore

Tags: certificate, acrobat, reader, truststore

We developed an application which signs PDF documents according to the PAdES standard. Yet, we have to register our intermediate and root certificates to Adobe Acrobat Reader from the application it self on each client. Is there any command line utility to automate this process?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Acrobat Customization Wizard DC (it's free) can help with that. There are a few manual steps to get it configured but after that, you can use your deployment tools to push out the security settings that include the certs. Basically, you configure one copy of Reader to be the way you want it then use the Wizard to push those settings out.

https://www.adobe.com/devnet-docs/acrobatetk/tools/Wizard/WizardDC/